# The pdf $p(x) = (x−2)^2$ exists on $1 ≤ x < b$. What is $b$ to three decimal places?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm somewhat confused by this question.

The pdf $p(x) = (x−2)^2$ exists on $1 ≤ x < b$. What is $b$ to three decimal places?

I know $p(x)$ is simply a normal parabola opening upwards with the vertex at $(2,0)$. I have never seen a pdf with this shape before, and I am confused on why the starting point at which the pdf exists is $x=1$.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: My best guess is you have to find the $b$ such that the function $\chi_{]1,b[}p$ is a probability density function, i.e. it's integral is 1.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thrown off because the function hits $0$ at $x=2$, and if you integrated $p(x)$ from $1$ to $2$ you get $\frac{1}{3}$. But I guess you can continue to go past $x=2$ to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew mentioned in the comment, if $p(x)$ is a density over $[1,b]$, then we have

$$\int_1^b (x-2)^2dx = \int_1^b x^2 - 4x +4 dx = 1$$

Solving this integral gives you

$$\frac{1}{3}b^3 - 2b^2 + 4b - \frac{1}{3} + 2 - 4 = 1$$

Now you just have to solve for the appropriate value of $b$ from the above.